# How to return model query result as JSON in scala play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using Play framework 2.1.1 with scala.I query a database table return to controller as list and then convert list to string and return to ajax call from javascript code.

How to return query result as json and return to ajax call throught controller?

**Application.scala**

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import views.html._
import models._


object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }

  def getSummaryTable = Action{
    var sum="Summary Table";
    Ok(ajax_result.render((Timesheet.getAll).mkString("\n")))
  }

  def javascriptRoutes = Action {  implicit request =>
    import routes.javascript._
    Ok(
    Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
          // Routes
          controllers.routes.javascript.Application.getSummaryTable

    )
    ).as("text/javascript")
  }  
}
```

**TimeSheet.scala**

```
// Use PostgresDriver to connect to a Postgres database
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._

import scala.slick.lifted.{MappedTypeMapper,BaseTypeMapper,TypeMapperDelegate}
import scala.slick.driver.BasicProfile
import scala.slick.session.{PositionedParameters,PositionedResult}
// Use the implicit threadLocalSession
import Database.threadLocalSession
import java.sql.Date
import java.sql.Time

case class Timesheet(ID: Int, dateVal: String, entryTime: Time, exitTime: Time, someVal: String)

object Timesheet {


 //Definition of Timesheet table
 // object TS extends Table[(Int,String,Time,Time,String)]("timesheet"){
  val TSTable = new Table[Timesheet]("timesheet"){
        def ID = column[Int]("id")
        def dateVal   = column[String]("date")
        def entryTime = column[Time]("entry_time")
        def exitTime  = column[Time]("exit_time")
        def someVal = column[String]("someval")

        def * = ID ~ dateVal ~ entryTime ~ exitTime ~ someVal <> (Timesheet.apply _, Timesheet.unapply _)
   }



  def getAll: Seq[Timesheet] = { 

 Database.forURL("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db", "postgres", "password",null, driver="org.postgresql.Driver") withSession{
  val q = Query(TSTable)
  val qFiltered = q.filter(_.ID === 41 )
  val qDateFilter = qFiltered.filter(_.dateVal === "01/03/2013")
  val qSorted = qDateFilter.sortBy(_.entryTime)

  qSorted.list

  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you use [`play.api.libs.Json.toJson`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Json$).

Here's an example:

```
object Products extends Controller {
  def list = Action {
  val productCodes = Product.findAll.map(_.ean)
  Ok(Json.toJson(productCodes))
}
```

`Json.toJson` returns a `JsValue` for which Play will automatically add a `application/json` header.

See [Play For Scala chapter 8](http://www.manning.com/hilton/).

Answer (score 6):

Also, don't forget to provide an implicit (or not) Json deserializer for your model, otherwise, Scala compiler will yell at you :-). You can do something like :

```
def allTimesheet = Action {
  val timesheetWrites = Json.writes[Timesheet] // here it's the deserializer
  val listofTimeSheet = Timesheet.getAll
  Ok( Json.toJson( listofTimeSheet )( timesheetWrites ) )
}
```

or you can use implicits like :

```
def allTimesheet = Action {
  implicit val timesheetWrites = Json.writes[Timesheet] // here it's the deserializer
  val listofTimeSheet = Timesheet.getAll
  Ok( Json.toJson( listofTimeSheet ) )
}
```

and even declare your deserializer in your model companion object like :

companion object

```
object Timesheet {
  implicit val timesheetWrites = Json.writes[Timesheet] // here it's the deserializer
  ....
}
```

and in the controller

```
import models.Timesheet.timesheetWrites

def allTimesheet = Action {
  val listofTimeSheet = Timesheet.getAll
  Ok( Json.toJson( listofTimeSheet ) )
}
```